# Computer spec and user name checking when installation application vb.net

Tags: vb.net-2010

I have a problem

I'm in making a VB.NET application,
I want to make my application running only in a specific computer name or user name,
So when somebody want to install my application in other computer the application installation will be aborted.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Environment class.

Username:

```
Environment.UserName
```

Machine Name

```
Environment.MachineName
```

The users can easily manipulate that though.
You should base it on HWID, altough they could still crack that :)